# typedef string c value assignment to position

Tags: c, arrays, string, variable-assignment, typedef

I used typedef in C as following:

```
typedef char string[20];
```

and then i created a function called "writeElement" defined as this:

```
void writeElement(string * string, int position, char letter){
     string[position]=letter;
}
```

why am I getting the error:

> "assignment to expression with array type"

I just can't understand.

Comment: Because `string[p]` has a type of `char[20]`

Comment: It's generally bad idea to hide arrays behind typedef, so confusing. Consider some variation of this instead: typedef struct { char data[20]; } string_t;

Comment: regarding: `typedef char string[20];`  this just says, when ever the source code contains "string[20]` to replace that with `char`.  This is not what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here, the `string` *type* is of type `char [20]`, an array type. A variable of type array, cannot be assigned, status by design.

In this case, the variable `string` is of type pointer to `string` type, which is a pointer to `char[20]` type (`char (*) [20]`, to be precise). Hence, `string[p]` is essentially of type `char [20]`, making it unusable for the LHS operand for assignment operator.

From what I see, you don't need the function parameter to be a pointer, in first place. Just make it of type `string` (choose a different variable name than a type, please), and index into it.

Also, when in doubt, check the data types. ON RHS of the assignment, you have type `char`, so the LHS also should be of the same type.

Comment: Thanks for replying. So how should I do to insert "letter" in "position" of the string passed as reference?

Comment: Just fix `writeElement(string str, int position, char letter)` and then `str[position]=letter;`

Answer (score 1):

First off, this is bad:

```
string * string
```

Because you define a variable with the same name as a type.  So the variable masks the name of the type, meaning you can't use the type in that scope.

The main problem is that the variable `string` has type `string *`, which translates to `char (*)[20]`, i.e. a pointer to an array.  So `string[position]` has type `char [20]`, which is an array type, and you can't assign to arrays.

Change the name of the `string` variable to something else, and change its type to `string`:

```
void writeElement(string my_string, int position, char letter){
     my_string[position]=letter;
}
```

Since passing an array to a function is the same as passing a pointer to its first element, you are able to dereference the pointer via the array element  operator `[]` so that the results are visible outside of the function.

This is an example of why it's not a good idea to hide pointers or arrays behind a `typedef`.  It leads to confusion as to what the actual type is.